# TextMate Comment Banner in Vim

Tags: vim, textmate

I am making the switch from TextMate to Vim for all of my text editing. However, one of the features that I used a lot in TextMate was the comment banner command (`ctr-shift-b`). It would create a banner and allow you to enter text inside the banner, and the banner would adjust to the length of the text. Is there any plugins, or any similiar feature in Vim? If not, is there a way I can program vim to make a comment banner? Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I currently use Snipmate.vim https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim

Although I am not completely sure there is a snippet that will match your exact need, it would
be trivial to add one that would do so!

It has *very* easy scripting to add whatever you need.

You would have to assign the snippet a certain key combination, so that when you are at that combination in insert mode and you hit Tab, the plugin inserts all the things you need plus it lets you change the text that you have previously set.

So for the example you give, I would give it a combination that says "banner". When I type that word and hit Tab, I would be placed in the "Comment Banner" so that I can type and replace the title.

This site has a very good video on how everything works: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-snipmate-vim/

Answer (score 6):

I've got these lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType vim map <leader>ccb I"<Del>  <Esc>A  "<Del><Esc>yyp0lv$hhr"yykPjj
autocmd FileType javascript,php,c map <leader>ccb I//  <Esc>A  //<Esc>yyp0llv$hhhr-yykPjj
autocmd FileType python,ruby,sh,zsh map <leader>ccb I#  <Esc>A  #<Esc>yyp0lv$hhr-yykPjj
autocmd FileType css map <leader>ccb I/*  <Esc>A  */<Esc>yyp0llv$r-$hc$*/<Esc>yykPjj
```

In `.vimrc` it turns this:

```
vimrc banner
```

into this:

```
""""""""""""""""""
"  vimrc banner  "
""""""""""""""""""
```

In a JS file it turns this:

```
javascript banner
```

into this:

```
//---------------------//
//  javascript banner  //
//---------------------//
```

Etc.

```
" Creating underline/overline headings for markup languages
" Inspired by http://sphinx.pocoo.org/rest.html#sections
nnoremap <leader>== yyP^v$r=jyyp^v$r=
nnoremap <leader>** yyP^v$r*jyyp^v$r*
nnoremap <leader>= yyp^v$r=
nnoremap <leader>- yyp^v$r-
nnoremap <leader>^ yyp^v$r^
nnoremap <leader>" yyp^v$r"
```

I wish I'd keep a link to where I found it, though.